# When should one use BytesIO .getvalue() instead of .getbuffer()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytesio

According to the [BytesIO docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

> getbuffer()
>
> Return a readable and writable view over the contents of the buffer without copying them. Also, mutating the view will transparently update the contents of the buffer:
>
> getvalue()
>
> Return bytes containing the entire contents of the buffer.

So it seems as if `getbuffer` is more complicated. But if you don't need a writable view? Would you then simply use `getvalue`? What are the trade-offs?

### Minimal Example

In this example, it seems as if they do exactly the same:

```
# Create an example
from io import BytesIO
bytesio_object = BytesIO(b"Hello World!")

# Write the stuff
with open("output.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytesio_object.getbuffer())
```

Comment: From the cpython code https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/bytesio.c here, it seems when you call getvalue will resize the content buffer to strip off extra buffer space if allocated and getbuffer will return the buffer as it is ready to be modified if needed.

Comment: @Kris `getvalue`seems to be faster than `getbuffer`. How can it be if getvalue makes a copy everytime ? plus, unlike `getbuffer`, `getvalue`always points to the same underlying object

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but it looks like nobody has answered this sufficiently.

Simply:

- `obj.getbuffer()` creates a `memoryview` object.
- Every time you write, or if there is a `memoryview` present, `obj.getvalue()` will need to create a new, complete value.
- If you have not written (since creation or since the last `obj.getvalue()` call) and there is no `memoryview` present, `obj.getvalue()` is the fastest method of access, and requires no copies.

That being the case:

- When creating another `io.BytesIO`, use `obj.getvalue()`
- For random-access reading and writing, *DEFINITELY* use `obj.getbuffer()`
- Avoid interpolating reading and writing frequently.  If you must, then *DEFINITELY* use `obj.getbuffer()`, unless your file is tiny.
- Avoid using `obj.getvalue()` while a buffer is laying around.

Here, we see that it's all fast, and all well and good if no buffer is laying around:

```py
# time getvalue()
>>> i = io.BytesIO(b'f' * 1_000_000)
>>> %timeit i.getvalue()
34.6 ns ± 0.178 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

# time getbuffer()
>>> %timeit i.getbuffer()
118 ns ± 0.495 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

# time getbuffer() and getvalue() together
>>> %timeit i.getbuffer(); i.getvalue()
173 ns ± 0.829 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Everything is fine, and working about like you'd expect.  But let's see what happens when there's a buffer just laying around:

```py
>>> x = i.getbuffer()
>>> %timeit i.getvalue()
33 µs ± 675 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Notice that we're no longer measuring in *nanoseconds*, we're measuring in *microseconds*.  That's multiple orders of magnitude slower.  If you `del x`, we're back to being fast.  This is all because while a `memoryview` exists, Python has to account for the possibility that the `BytesIO` may have been written to.  So, to give a definite state to the user, it copies the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Using getbuffer() is better, because, if you have really BIG data, copying them may take a long time. And (from [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

But value is undefined - it may be str or bytes. Buffer is always bytes.

Comment: `getvalue`seems to be faster than `getbuffer`. How can it be if getvalue makes a copy everytime ? plus, unlike `getbuffer`, `getvalue`always points to the same underlying object

Comment: "But value is undefined" no it isnt. `io.BytesIO.getvalue` always returns `bytes`